# How to get rid of the 'No records found message' in PrimeNG datatable?

Tags: primeng, primeng-datatable

I created a data table using PrimeNG. I just created 2 headings for the datatable. I'll actually fetch the data from the server, hence if there is no data I do not want the default 'No records found message' to be shown.

I would like the table to be empty if there is no data in the table.

Please take a look at the table that I have created below :

```
<p-dataTable>
       <p-headerColumnGroup >
         <p-row>
           <p-column header="Weekday"></p-column>
           <p-column header="Set Class Time"></p-column>

         </p-row>
       </p-headerColumnGroup>
 </p-dataTable>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `emptyMessage` property to override this message :

```
<p-dataTable emptyMessage="">
    ...
</p-dataTable>
```

**Edit :**
If you don't want to see the border, hide `ui-datatable-emptymessage` class with CSS. Btw, you don't need to use `emptyMessage` property anymore in that case.

```
.ui-datatable-emptymessage {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: I'll try it and let you know

Comment: Yes, it's working. No records found message is hidden now but I'm getting a border for my columns with empty data, Is there a way to avoid it too, I mean is there any default variable with which I can  write an if condition to hide the borders