# Primeng don't display empty Message-row

Tags: angular, primeng

I use with Primeng datatable
when No records found it display a row with message, how can I hide this row?

```
<p-dataTable>
              <p-column [style]="{'width': '500px'}" header="Artifacts">
                  <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-col>
                      <textarea rows="3" cols="30" style="width: 100%" pInputTextarea [(ngModel)]="parametersForAll['Artifacts']"
                      placeholder="Artifacts ..."></textarea>
                  </ng-template>
                </p-column> 
    </p-dataTable>
```

Comment: <p-dataTable>
              <p-column [style]="{'width': '500px'}" header="Artifacts">
                  <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-col>
                      <textarea rows="3" cols="30" style="width: 100%" pInputTextarea [(ngModel)]="parametersForAll['Artifacts']"
                      placeholder="Artifacts ..."></textarea>
                  </ng-template>
                </p-column> 
             
    </p-dataTable>

Comment: Please, check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48108916/how-to-get-rid-of-the-no-records-found-message-in-prime-ng-data-table/48109038#48109038

Answer (score 0):

You can disable that with the help of following css

```
.ui-datatable-emptymessage{
display:none
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by looks ok but not showing? did it work?