# p-dataTable display empty Message-row, how can I hide it

Tags: angular, primeng

I use with Primeng datatable
when No records found it display a row with message, how can I hide this row?

```
<p-dataTable>
              <p-column [style]="{'width': '500px'}" header="Artifacts">
                  <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-col>
                      <textarea rows="3" cols="30" style="width: 100%" pInputTextarea [(ngModel)]="parametersForAll['Artifacts']"
                      placeholder="Artifacts ..."></textarea>
                  </ng-template>
                </p-column> 
    </p-dataTable>
```

this css doesn't work for me:

```
.ui-datatable-emptymessage{
display:none
}
```

Comment: What version of primeng are you using?

Comment: "primeng": "^4.1.1", and "version": "4.2.2",

Comment: I did the same thing and it is working. Check this plnkr --> http://plnkr.co/edit/dXb9kHw4xrZY6jc9RGsJ?p=preview

Comment: Also, where did you put that css? Within a component? Or global styles.css file?

Comment: thx! I put it in global styles.css and now it's working well!!!!

Comment: Please, check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48108916/how-to-get-rid-of-the-no-records-found-message-in-prime-ng-data-table/48109038#48109038

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Primeng don't display empty Message-row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851128/primeng-dont-display-empty-message-row)

Answer (score 2):

You did not mention it but you probably put that css in your component css file. Since, by default, component's encapsulation is `Emulated`, 
it will generate your styles with custom attributes.

I.e.

```
.ui-datatable-emptymessage{
    display:none
}
```

becomes something like following after compilation

```
.ui-datatable-emptymessage[_ng-content0]{
    display:none
}
```

Therefore, it does not apply to primeng. You can either put this css in global styles.css file or change `ViewEncapsulation` of your component to `None`

e.g.

```
@Component({
   selector: 'my-comp',
   template: '',
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

For more info, [check the docs.](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation)